# System.ServiceModel.Web .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm porting a .NET Framework application into .NET Core. I've added via NuGet System.ServiceModel.Web but it seem not work. I need an alternativ to "WebGet":

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IChannelsApi
{
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json), OperationContract]
    List<Channel> GetChannels();

    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "{name}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json), OperationContract]
    Channel GetChannel(string name);

}
```

What I have to do?

Comment: Can you give us a [mcve]? A simple controller class with one GET method that you've tried that doesn't work.

Comment: It's an interface. I've provided you more code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Thomas noted, WebGet has been long superseded with much better frameworks for creating REST APIs.  If you haven't already, go and create a new .Net Core Web Api project in VS2015 / VS2017, run it, then see how it differs to the old WCF method.  You'll notice that a lot less boilerplate code and decorating is required. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9452105/2869344) a rundown of some differences between WCF and ASP.NET Web API, and .Net Core is really just the next generation of this.

Below is a more comprehensive example of some code from a working controller class. If required, you can abstract this into an interface, but [there's probably no point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15411734/2869344). Also notice the lack of `[ServiceContract]` and `[OperationContract]` decorations, among other things. Just specify the `[Route(...)]` (optional - if the controller doesn't conform to the default route), and the method and Uri path using `[HttpGet(...)]`, etc.

This code also assumes a few things such as dependencies being registered with the DI container (`ILogger` and `ICustomerRepository`). Note that .Net Core has dependency injection built in, which is a nice feature ([Quick rundown](https://jonhilton.net/2016/11/17/start-using-dependency-injection-asp-net-core/)).

Finally, I also recommend using [Swagger](http://swagger.io/) if you are not already. I'm late to the party on this one but have been using it lately and it is a boon for API development (the extensive commenting below assists in making Swagger more useful):

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class CustomersController : Controller
    {
        ILogger<CustomersController> log;
        ICustomerRepository customerRepository;

        public CustomersController(ILogger<CustomersController> log, ICustomerRepository customerRepository)
        {
            this.log = log;
            this.customerRepository = customerRepository;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get a specific customer 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="customerId">The id of the Customer to get</param>
        /// <returns>A customer  with id matching the customerId param</returns>
        /// <response code="200">Returns the customer </response>
        /// <response code="404">If a customer  could not be found that matches the provided id</response>
        [HttpGet("{customerId:int}")]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(ApiResult<Customer>), 200)]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(ApiResult), 404)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetCustomer([FromRoute] int customerId)
        {
            try
            {
                return Ok(new ApiResult<Customer>(await customerRepository.GetCustomerAsync(customerId)));
            }
            catch (ResourceNotFoundException)
            {
                return NotFound(new ApiResult($"No record found matching id {customerId}"));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: And `ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json` ?

Comment: Not required in the controller if you are using JSON everywhere.  See answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847564/how-do-i-get-asp-net-web-api-to-return-json-instead-of-xml-using-chrome/26068063#26068063) to explicitly return json when browsing with Chrome, otherwise just ensure you set the correct `Content-Type` header in your request.

Comment: Also make sure you see the edit I made about not needing to create an interface.  That's not really how Web Api is designed.

Comment: Learn ASP.NET. There are hundreds of details you need to consider before putting something on a network beyond this three or four features in this sample.

Answer (score 3):

System.ServiceModel.Web is not supported on .NET Standard or .NET Core. This is especially true for the deprecated WCF technology stack in general.

Luckily for you, the WebGet concept of WCF is an attempt to cover HTTP REST interfaces by the WCF stack. That however was ultimately superseded by ASP.NET WebApi and later ASP.NET Core.

Use ASP.NET Core to create the same interface.

Comment: Can you please give me an example?

Comment: I think every intro tutorial on ASP.NET Core for web API usage covers your needs. Dotnet new sample project will do.