# Migrate from WCF to .NET Core, WebGet, WebInvoke

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am investigating possibility to migrate an old project to .NET Core. It is currently using .NET 4.5.1.

Now this is a large project so I am considering if it is possible to do it step by step. Is it possible to include .NET Core libraries in the .NET project and start using the new ASP.NET Web API like described in [System.ServiceModel.Web .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44562141/system-servicemodel-web-net-core) ?

I have a couple of web services like this that I would like to convert to .NET Core, but I do not want to convert the entire project to .NET Core yet:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IChannelsApi
{
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json), OperationContract]
    List<Channel> GetChannels();

    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "{name}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json), OperationContract]
    Channel GetChannel(string name);

}
```

Comment: You can convert libraries to .NET Standard, which will allow them to be used in both Core and Framework, but you cannot run a project as a whole "half" on Core and "half" on Framework. It's one or the other. If you mean "solution" rather than "project", you can of course have individual projects running on Core or Framework as you please.

Comment: @JeroenMostert could you please add this as an answer?